# Pass coordinates using HTML 5 "data-" tag

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, google-maps

I need to pass coordinates to javascript from HTML 5 using the data- tag for use in Google Maps. I am not very good at Javascript and I cannot find a solution anywhere. This is the html with ruby(erb), the coordinates are correctly available in HTML if the page source is viewed:

```
<div id="google_map_section" data-latitude="<%= @place.latitude %>" data-longtitude ="<%= @place.longtitude %>"></div>
```

And the javascript:

```
$(function initialize() {
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(
        parseFloat($("#google_map_section").attr("data-latitude")),
        parseFloat($("#google_map_section").attr("data-longtitude"))
    );
    var myOptions = {
        zoom: 12,
        center: latlng,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE
    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("google_map_section"),
    myOptions);
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
       position: myLatlng, 
       map: map
    });

});
```

Question 1: The values are not being passed to javascript. Why not? Should I use:

```
 $("#google_map_section").data("latitude")?
 $("#google_map_section").attr("data-latitude")?
 $("#google_map_section").getAttribute("data-latitude")?
```

I tried them all with no luck. Sometimes the map seems to render but no images are shown.

Question 2: Do I have to use onload="initialize()" on the body tag or can it be used on any tag?

Comment: Thanks to both of you! I was apparently very close, deleting the initialize() did the trick!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using attr should work fine:

[Working example](http://jsfiddle.net/VC8cJ/)

You do not need to use the onload inline event handler however your initialise method should be an anonymous method instead of a named method.

Replace:

```
$(function initialize() {
```

with:

```
$(function() { // Shortcut for $(document).ready(function(){});
```

Answer (score 1):

For #1, `$("#google_map_section").attr('data-latitude')` should work.

For #2, You should do it like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var latlong // etc.
});
```

which will run that javascript when the document is ready (i.e. when the page has finished loading and all DOM objects have been rendered). My guess is that this is why the answer to #1 wasn't working, because the google_map_section object hadn't been loaded yet.